# Problem running a function every X seconds between 4 am and 9:30 am

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js server running a timed task to get data from an API every X seconds between 4 am EST and 9:30 EST, so premarket trading session, but it still continues to query the API and still prints "Time between specified ranges".

First, I check if it's a market holiday then check the time if it's between certain hours.

Here is the function to check the time:

```
function checkTime() {
const estNow = new Date(now.toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));
const estHour = estNow.getHours();
const estMinute = estNow.getMinutes();

if((estHour >= 4 && estHour <= 9) || estHour === 9 && estMinute <= 30){
    console.log('Time between specified ranges');
    return true;
} 
console.log('Not between 4 am and 9:30 am EST');
return false;

// bypass
//return true;

}
```

Main code for API calls:

```
async function main() {
const startTime = Date.now(); // To time how long function takes
var timeRight = checkTime();
var isMarketHoliday();
if (timeRight && !isMarketHoliday) {
    try {
       // Await api calls
   
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
}
const endTime = Date.now();
console.log(`Function took: ${endTime - startTime} ms`);
}
```

And I call main every x seconds:

```
  setInterval(main, 25000); // run every 25 seconds
```

It doesn't need to run exactly at 4 am, just after that because that is when the markets start in premarket session. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: `estHour <= 9` should probably be `estHour < 9`

Comment: You need to give your `setInterval()` a name so that you can call `clearInterval()` on it later.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't stop after 9:30," do you mean that it keeps on printing out `"Not between 4 am and 9:30 am EST"`? If that's the case, it makes sense because `setInterval` will run the function repeatedly forever regardless of what the function's return value is. If that's not the case, then there's an error in your time checking logic.

Comment: I meant it still prints "Time between specified ranges" and queries the API. I forgot to copy the console and post it this morning.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: What is the problem? I am having a hard time trying to figure out what your issue is.

Comment: It is supposed  to stop quering the API after 9:30 but it continues. The time check logic is wrong I think. I want to query the API every say, 30 secs between 4 am and 9:30 am.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to run a task between certain hours, I used Unix Timestamps to easily check if the current time is in the specified ranges.

```
function getUnixTimestamp(dateString) {
var futureTime = new Date(dateString);
var futureTimestamp = futureTime.getTime();
var futureUnixTimestamp = Math.floor(futureTimestamp);
return futureUnixTimestamp;
}


function checkTime() {
    var now = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US");
    const rightNow = Date.now();
    const premarketEnd = getUnixTimestamp(now + ' 09:30:00');
    const premarketStart = getUnixTimestamp(now + ' 04:00:00');
    const currentTime = new Date(rightNow).toLocaleTimeString("en-US")
    if(rightNow > premarketStart && rightNow < premarketEnd) {
        console.log(`The current time is ${currentTime} and is between 
specified ranges.`)
    return true;
    } else {
        console.log(`The current time is ${currentTime} and outside 
        specified ranges.`)
        return false;
    }
}
```